# Amazon DynamoDB Client - SDK V3.0: SerializationException in query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Recently I updated my code with the newest AWS SDK version 3

I have the function to query in dynamodb as below:

```
const query = async ( _eventId, _roomId) => {
  var params = {
    TableName: 'myTable',
    IndexName: 'p_key-status-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'p_key = :p_key AND #status = :status',
    FilterExpression: 'contains(room_id, :room_id)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: marshall({
      '#status': 'status'
    }),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall({
      ':p_key':  _eventId,
      ':room_id': _roomId,
      ':status': true
    })
  };

  console.log('getRegSeat :: params: ' + JSON.stringify(params));

  try {
    let res = await dynamoClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
    console.log('res: ', res);

    return true
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: ' + e);
  }
};
```

I received an error

```
Error: SerializationException: Start of structure or map found where not expected
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue:

`ExpressionAttributeNames` doesn't work with `marshall`

My fix: I removed `marshall` and everything worked like charm.

```
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#status': 'status'
    }
```

I don't know if it's a bug or it's a design of AWS. If it's a design, it's such an inconsistent design, a bit confusing for a newcomer like me.

Comment: Perfect, I had the same issue, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide us with _eventId and _roomId? maybe there are some special characters that needs to be handled or something

Comment: There's no special characters in eventId and roomId. For example:  eventId='EVENT#001', roomId='A_001'

Comment: @francophong Could you test with eventId without the # character, It could be interpreted the same as #status = :status?